# JASIG CAS certificate

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, single-sign-on, cas

We have some problems with SSO (single sign on) authentication. We use JASIG CAS and our implmentation  is not working. It  is allert  "You are currently accessing CAS over a non-secure connection. Single Sign On WILL NOT WORK. In order to have single sign on work, you MUST log in over HTTPS." But we added the sertificate to Tomcat server.xml
[image: PAGE]
our settings in server.xml

```
<Connector port="8443"
  protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
  SSLEnabled="true"
  maxThreads="150"
  scheme="https"
  secure="true"
  clientAuth="false"
  sslProtocol="TLS"
  keyAlias="myalias"
  keystoreFile="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\ssoServer.jks"
  keystorePass="12345678" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you did add the cert, then why are you going over localhost and 8080?

Comment: You configured port 8443. Wanna try that instead?